# plot with only horizontal gridlines and labels

Tags: r, plot

I have some barplot

```
barplot(1:3, axes=FALSE)
```

to which I would like to add horizontal gridlines with labels using base R.

I get the first part using

```
par(xpd = TRUE, mai=c(0.5,1,0.5,0.2))  # to extend lines to the left of plotting area
barplot(1:3, axes=FALSE)               # plotting area
grid(nx=0, ny=3, col="gray")           # horizontal grid lines
barplot(1:3, axes=FALSE, add=TRUE)     # get grid lines into background
```

but I fail to get the labels on the left end. That is, at the left end of the gridlines, I would like to have the Y-values, here 1 and 2.

Comment: I can't post expected output but added description to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of `?grid` gives a solution to this problem. From section Note.

> Note
>
> If more fine tuning is required, use `abline(h = ., v = .)` directly.

```
old_par <- par(xpd = TRUE, mai=c(0.5,1,0.5,0.2)) 

barplot(1:3, axes = FALSE)
abline(h = 1:3, col = "grey", lty = "dotted")
barplot(1:3, axes = FALSE, add = TRUE)
text(x = -0.5, y = 1:3, labels = 1:3)

par(old_par)
```

[image]

To have the y axis labels at the end of the grid lines and to place them automatically, a function can be defined.

```
segmText <- function(x0, x1, y, ...){
  segments(x0 = x0, x1 = x1,
           y0 = y, y1 = y, ...)
  text(x = x0, y = y, labels = y)

}

old_par <- par(xpd = TRUE, mai = c(0.5,1,0.5,0.2))  # to extend lines to the left of plotting area
barplot(1:3, axes = FALSE)
segmText(x0 = -0.5, x1 = 4, y = 1:3, col = "grey", lty = "dotted")
barplot(1:3, axes = FALSE, add = TRUE)
par(old_par)
```

**Edit**

A simpler solution seems to be in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58488240/plot-with-only-horizontal-gridlines-and-labels/58488645#comment103309343_58488645) by user [d.b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7128934/d-b)

```
graphics.off()
barplot(1:3, axes = FALSE, col = NA, border = NA)
abline(h = 1:3, col = "grey", lty = "dotted")
barplot(1:3, axes = FALSE, add = TRUE)
axis(2, at = 1:3, labels = 1:3, las = 2, col = NA)
```

Comment: Is there a way of getting the labels to the end of the gridlines?

Comment: And is there a way of placing them automatically with the grid lines?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `lines()` within a `sapply()` and use `mtext()`. Plot an empty plot beforehand.

```
plot(x=0:4, y=0:4, type="n", axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")
sapply(1:3, function(x) lines(0:4, rep(x, 5), lty=3, col="gray"))
barplot(1:3, axes=FALSE, add=TRUE)
mtext(1:3, side=2, line=0, at=1:3, las=1, adj=0)
```

You can trim this by changing e.g. `line=-1` or play around with `adj`.

#### Produces

[image]